# Android - Create a Socket in Singleton

Tags: java, android, sockets, singleton

Im developing an android game. I was trying to create a socket in an Activity where the match is placed, but the app is crashing when I create. I was searching for this problem and I was advised to create a socket in a Singleton class. But the app continues to crash when I try to create a socket.

```
public class SingletonConnection extends OnlineGame {
    private Socket socket;
    private SingletonConnection() throws IOException {
        InetAddress serverAddr =InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
        this.socket = new Socket(serverAddr, server_port); //CRASHA AQUI
        this.inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
        this.outToServer = new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(),true);

    }

    public static SingletonConnection getSingletonConnection() throws IOException {
        if (ref == null)
            // it's ok, we can call this constructor
            ref = new SingletonConnection();
        return ref;
    }

    public Object clone()
            throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
        // that'll teach 'em
    }
    public void WriteToSocket(String string){
        this.outToServer.println(string);
    }
    public String ReadFromServer() throws IOException {
        return this.inFromServer.readLine();
    }
    private static SingletonConnection ref;
    private static BufferedReader inFromServer;
    private static PrintWriter outToServer;
    public static final int server_port = 6000;
    public static final String hostname = "192.168.1.65";
}
```

I Call the Singleton class here

```
public void getInformationFromServer() throws IOException {
    SingletonConnection conect = SingletonConnection.getSingletonConnection();

    try {
        String playerString = conect.ReadFromServer();
        String[] players = playerString.split(",");
        initPlayers(players);
        String cardString = inFromServer.readLine();
        String playedCard = inFromServer.readLine();
        initDeck(cardString,playedCard);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.martins.highcards, PID: 5497
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.martins.highcards/com.example.martins.highcards.OnlineGame}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
                  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:333)
                  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
                  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
                  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
                  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)
                  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:535)
                  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:427)
                  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:210)
                  at com.example.martins.highcards.SingletonConnection.<init>(SingletonConnection.java:19)
                  at com.example.martins.highcards.SingletonConnection.getSingletonConnection(SingletonConnection.java:28)
                  at com.example.martins.highcards.OnlineGame.getInformationFromServer(OnlineGame.java:93)
                  at com.example.martins.highcards.OnlineGame.onCreate(OnlineGame.java:66)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is for English Q/A-s.

Comment: `Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. And we never Google dont we?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens when you try to do a network operation on the main thread. The system protects itself from freezing because some operations might have a lot of load time and could freeze the UI.

Instead use AsynkTask or run it on a diferent Thread.

```
public ReadingThread readThread;
public int localPORT = 12345;

public void startReadingThread(){
    if (readThread == null || (!readThread.isAlive())){
        try {
            //define the socket but with null value
            listener = new DatagramSocket(null);
            listener.bind(new InetSocketAddress(localPORT));
            readThread = new ReadingThread();
            readThread.start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            return ex.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
public void stopReadingThread(){
    //stop the thread
    if (readThread != null && (readThread.isAlive()))
    {
        readThread.stop();
        readThread = null;
    }
    //disconnect the socket
    if (listener != null){
        listener.disconnect();
        listener.close();
    }
}
public class ReadingThread extends Thread {
    public void stop(){
        continue = false;
    }
    public boolean continue = true;
    public void run() {
        while(continue)
        {
            try
            {
                final String readingFeed = receiveData(listener);
                if (readingFeed != null){
                    //execute next code on main Thread (UI update, etc)
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            //do something with the data received
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //showToast("Receiving Error: " + ex.toString());
                //continue = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
public String[] receiveData(DatagramSocket socket)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] buf = new byte[padre.configAdmin.buffer_size];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        socket.receive(packet);
        String data = new String(packet.getData());
        return data;
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return new String[] {"IOError: " + e.getMessage()};
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new String[] {"ExError: " + e.getMessage()};
    }
}
```

For this I recommend thread, but AsynkTask would work as good as a diferent Thread, also AsynkTask has many functions that work directly on the Main Thread, and you dont need to use the runOnUiThread section of code (like mine).

Comment: But when i read the data 
     final String readingFeed = receiveData(listener);
, how can i put the data that i received from the Server on my Game Class?

Comment: In the class that is in charge of the network communitaction you may want to have a reference to the GameClass,so in the section qhere i wrote `//do something with the data...` send the data to the GameClass with a function `GameClass.dataArraived(readingFeed)`, or something like this.

Comment: Actually there are a lot of ways you can pass data from one object to another, you can implement a listener, you can have a reference of the NetworkClass int the GameClass, you can have a FatherClass that have the two classes as childs and use this FatherClass as a mean of communication between the objects, etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SocketIOInitialization {

    public Socket socket;
    private static String SOCKET_URL = "/*put socket url he";
    private static final Map<Integer, SocketIOInitialization> socketIOInitialization = new HashMap<>();
    private static final Map<Integer, Socket> sockets = new HashMap<>();
    private int userId;

    private SocketIOInitialization(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;

        socketIOInitialization.put(userId, connectSocket(userId));
        sockets.put(userId, this.socket);

    }

    public static SocketIOInitialization getSocketInstance(int userId) {
        if (null == socketIOInitialization.get(userId)) {
            new SocketIOInitialization(userId);
        }
        return socketIOInitialization.get(userId);
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return sockets.get(this.userId);
    }

    private SocketIOInitialization connectSocket(int userId) {
        try {


            //if you are using a phone device you should connect to same local network as your laptop and disable your pubic firewall as well

            IO.Options mOptions = new IO.Options();
            mOptions.query = "userId=" + userId;
            socket = IO.socket(SOCKET_URL, mOptions);


            //create connection

            socket.connect();


            //emit the event join along side with the nickname
            Log.d("onCreate socket ", "on");
            return this;


        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: yes will solve the problem as you can call it in any class in the code as SocketIOInitialization.getSocketInstance(user.id); this to create connection and         socket=SocketIOInitialization.getSocketInstance(user.id).getSocket();
 to make sure the connection is establish if found before will return the same  socket and if not found will return the one one for this user